# how to set environment variable for root user

Tags: macos, environment, sudo, pythonpath

I'm Mac user.

I want to set PYTHONPATH env for root. so

```
$ sudo su -
# vi ~/.profile
```

and add to file 'export PYTHONPATH=/mypythonlib'

then

```
# env
```

I can see this line

```
PYTHONPATH=/Users/simpnet2/projects/meiji/src/hershey
```

but..

when I use sudo command, cannot find that

```
$ sudo env
```

.. there's no PYTHONPATH

My program has to run with sudo command and needs `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Please read [how to format questions on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use sh try `/etc/profile`, bash try `/etc/bashrc` and if you use zsh try `/etc/zshenv`.

Comment: one thing to add... if on ``ubuntu``, bash try ``/etc/bash.bashrc``

Answer (score 6):

You can make PYTHONPATH visible to sudo be editing your sudoers file. Notice you should ONLY do this through visudo [as explained here](http://craiccomputing.blogspot.com/2010/10/setting-environment-variables-for-sudo.html).

Comment: The best answer. Actually, the only that works for me.

Answer (score 5):

You should try `sudo -i` which will simulate logging in as `root` and source the `~root/.profile`.

Answer (score 1):

As of 10.8.5, putting my environment statements in the .profile path in the home of the root user (/var/root) worked. after quitting bash and coming back to the root user prompt with 'su -', I could see my new path, etc. with the 'env' command **and** my MacPorts installationw orking correctly.

```
MacBook-Pro:~ root# cat /var/root/.profile
export MANPATH=/opt/local/share/man:$MANPATH
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
MacBook-Pro:~ root# which port
/opt/local/bin/port
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, in other Linux system, it is also right that 'sudo' does not use local environment variable. But you can declare the temporary environment variable along with 'sudo' command.

For example, in your case, you can add 'PYTHONPATH=/mypythonlib' in your command 'sudo env', and the final command is:

```
sudo PYTHONPATH=/mypythonlib env
```

You can also read this article: [Using sudo](http://aplawrence.com/Basics/sudo.html). You can see how 'sudo' keep or ignore user-defined environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of logging in as a normal user and invoking "su - root" I found that Mac OS 10.8.5's bash was ignoring .profile and .bash_profile; I was unable to change root's $PATH by editing those files. What did work was editing /etc/paths. After exiting the root shell and entering again with "su - root" the new path was present.